# Add fields to existing TFS Work Items?

Tags: tfs, workitem, tfs-workitem, tfs-power-tools

I need to add some fields to my work item types in an existing team project to support integration with other toolsets. However, after adding those fields in my work item type definitions using the [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) Process Editor, and following [the instructions detailed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh409273.aspx), the tickets still do not contain this field. Instead, it is only new tickets that are created with this field.

Is it possible to add a field to existing TFS work items, rather than just updating the Work Item Type Definition for future work items?

We're using Visual Studio 2012 and Tfs 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if this question is invalid; upon adding the field, the existing work items are indeed updated with the new field. However, a restart of visual studio is required in order to see the field on existing tickets, while new tickets have the field visible immediately. This can cause confusion about the state of the system for the user (me).

Comment: You don't need to restart VS, but you do need to do a "Refresh" on the Work Items Panel (or right click Refresh Work Items in VS2010).

Comment: I won't be able to reproduce this until next time I edit my WITDs, but I performed this specific action since it's enumerated as step 5 in the instructions I link in the OP. This didn't work for me, and is in fact why I opened the question. Perhaps it's because I had already opened the Work Item in question once in the same session?

Comment: If you had the work item already opened in detailed view, these wouldn't be updated by a refresh in Team Explorer. You would also need to refresh the work item view itself.