# Customize Team Foundation Server Work Item Template

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a default template for work item (test case, bugs, user story etc) but it has limited number of fields, can someone help me how can I add more fields to my existing template to gather more information for each work item. I am admin for my project in Team Foundation Server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a fairly simple process when you have the Team Foundation Server Power tools installed. If you want to store these workitem definitions in sourcecontrol (for later updates), then [here's a nice walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2013/02/13/tfs-how-to-customize-work-item-types.aspx).

You can also [use the Team Foundation Server Power tools directly](http://geekswithblogs.net/KirstinJ/archive/2008/06/23/customize-your-tfs-template.aspx) to update the workitems directly on the server. This is not recommended if you want to distribute your updates to multiple team projects. But I find it an easy way to apply the changes I want to a temporary team project, then download the changed template to then distribute it to all the other projects.

Be sure to [restart Visual Studio after changing the work item definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454507/add-fields-to-existing-tfs-work-items) or you will possibly need to force [Team Explorer to refresh the local cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121452/how-to-add-edit-items-to-the-predefined-lists-in-tfs-work-items/11121611#11121611).

Comment: Can you please provide me a resource to edit work item using 2012. And I tried to add one more field in my existing work-item, but it does not give any information about were it will be placed on UI. As well as what data should I will in the text box provided

Comment: Are you using the Team Foundation Server Power Tools? There are multiple tabs on a work item. Field definitions, Workflow state and UI. You might need to add your field to each of these tabs. See also: http://amosdk.blogspot.nl/2010/09/how-to-add-custom-field-to-existing.html